# How can i see a combo in al window forms in c#

Tags: c#

Hy.
I want to use the combo selected item from form1 in form 2 and i don't know how in c#.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

- When opening Form2, pass the object containing Form1 as a reference.
- In Form2, access the combo box using this object either

  - directly (note that this might require changing the access modifier of the combo box from `protected` to `public`) or
  - (more elegantly) by calling a public method of Form1 written by you that returns the selected item of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to pass a reference in form 2's constructor. Suppose the following code is in Form1.cs.

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Tag = myCombo;
f.showDialog();
```

You can operate the combo in Form2 by getting the tag and parse it to ComboBox. A better way:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
Dictionary<string,object> controlsInForm1 = new Dictionary<string,object>();
controlsInForm1.Add("combo",myCombo);
controlsInForm1.Add("label",myLabel);
f.Tag = controlsInForm1;
f.showDialog();
```

Now you can operate controls in Form1 safely without complex constructor of Form2.

Answer (score 0):

pass a reference to the combo box in form 1 to form 2, possible in form 2's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a read only public property which returns the selected item.

```
public object ComboValue
{
    get 
    {
        return combo.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

In stead of object, use the proper class/type.